# How add text in the hover effect of this triangle in svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I made a triangle with hover effect, but I can´t add text. How can I add text inside the hover effect of this polygon?

html :

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="formas" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 792 612" enable-background="new 0 0 792 612" xml:space="preserve">
   <linearGradient id="triangulo_apartado_1_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="252.5721" x2="117.5039" y2="252.5721">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5D676A"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#808B91"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5D676A"/>
   </linearGradient>
   <polygon class="triangle" id="triangulo_apartado_1"  fill="url(#triangulo_apartado_1_1_)"stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="117.504,281.948 0,281.948 58.752,223.196"/>
</svg>
```

style in css:

```
.triangle{} .triangle:hover{fill:#ffcd00;}
```

Comment: Please explain why the duplicate is not helping you rather than keep asking the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a text element immediately after the triangle. The text has `fill-opacity:0;`
when you hover over the triangle the opacity of the text changes to 1:

```
.triangle:hover + text{fill-opacity:1;pointer-events:none}
```

```css
text{fill-opacity:0;}
.triangle:hover{fill:#ffcd00;}
.triangle:hover + text{fill-opacity:1;pointer-events:none}
```

```html
<svg version="1.0" id="formas" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 792 612" enable-background="new 0 0 792 612" xml:space="preserve">
   <linearGradient id="triangulo_apartado_1_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="0" y1="252.5721" x2="117.5039" y2="252.5721">
      <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5D676A"/>
      <stop  offset="0.4845" style="stop-color:#808B91"/>
      <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5D676A"/>
   </linearGradient>
   <polygon class="triangle" id="triangulo_apartado_1"  fill="url(#triangulo_apartado_1_1_)"stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="117.504,281.948 0,281.948 58.752,223.196"/>
   
 <text x="35" y="270" >triangle</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!